# Javascript kinetics focus event, display, rect

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am using kinetics Javascript. I draw a couple of rect, it smooths. When mouse focus on Rect, I want to show some points/joints on the rect, so that it gives hints rect could be linked with each other by this particular points/joints. I have other pictures also, for example triangle, it shall also has joints. How to have a figure(Rect for example) when it is normal state and another state with little bit changed figure when mouse focuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to display a "linkable" icon on top of any rectangle that the mouse enters and remove that icon when the mouse leaves.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6dgAD/

[image] [image]

You can handle mouseenter and mouseleave events on your rectangles like this:

This code puts a Kinetic.Image containing a "linkable" icon over the rect.

```
rect.on("mouseenter",function(){
    link.setPosition(this.getPosition());
    link.show();
    layer.draw();
});
rect.on("mouseleave",function(){
    link.hide();
    layer.draw();
});
```

Here's an example of how you might create a "linkable" icon using Kinetic.Image:

```
var link;
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    link=new Kinetic.Image({
        image:img,
        listening:false,
    });
    layer.add(link);
    link.hide();
    layer.draw();
}
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stack1/addLink.png";
```